# Drupal: Content type page based on custom node concept

Tags: php, drupal

Is there a way to set a custom content type page to a custom node concept via the template files? I.e. posting an event, but I want the event page to have some exclusive custom modules + css outside of the standard node template.

Comment: What do you mean exclusive custom modules? You can definitely have custom css for your event page

Comment: Well I mean as in outside of just CSS for the page; as in basing off a separate template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a different template for a node type (that still sits in the content area of your themes `page.tpl.php` file), just get the machine name of your content type and copy the node.tpl.php file from `root/modules/node` to `your_theme/templates/` and rename it `node--MACHINE_NAME.tpl.php`. Clear your cache and it will start being picked up by Drupal.

To reformat an entire page is quite similar. Copy `root/modules/system/page.tpl.php` to your `your_theme/templates/` and rename it to `page--MACHINE_NAME.tpl.php`. Clear your cache and you're ready to go.

You can style individual nodes by using the node template method above but replacing the machine name with your node nid.